# Where does the value for "Description" come from in ID3 tags created by GarageBand

Tags: mp3, id3, garageband

I have made some music in GarageBand '09, and when I export it, there is some strange data in the ID3 tags. When I open the MP3 in VLC, and view the meta data, there is field called Description and it contains a long string of hex. Everything else is correct. Is this a hash or fingerprint of my song or what?

Answer (score 2):

The hex string often seen in ID3v2 "Comment" field is [iTunes SoundCheck information](http://www.id3.org/iTunes_Normalization_settings) used for normalizing the sound volume, similar to ReplayGain.

The information is stored in ID3v2 `COMM`ent frame with description `iTunNORM`, and iTunes usually hides it. However, most ID3v2 tools treat it as any other comment.

Comment: Thanks, can't upvote yet. So I assume that VLC does not use this information. Would I be correct then to assume that the song will sound differently if I play it in iTunes?

Comment: @emkman: If "Sound Check" is enabled in Preferences, yes. See [this Apple page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2425). _(Regarding upvoting, [see here](http://superuser.com/faq#howtoask))_